# Not all objects showing on the array

Tags: php

I created a table with two columns (ID and username) using PHPMyAdmin and added 1 row from the same interface. Then using PHP I added multiple rows. On PHPMyAdmin, I see the new added rows --the code I used to add the new rows is below. But when I retrieve the array on the site with the code below, I only see the very first row I added using PHPMyAdmin.

Any idea as to why and also how can I get all the data on the array?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `allusers` (`ID`, `Username`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'abracadabra')";
```

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)){
    print_r ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
```

Answer (score 0):

[`mysqli_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) gives you, in array form, the column data of the "next" row (where "next" is determined by a cursor internal to your resultset object `$result`).

You should call it subsequent times to get subsequent rows (usually in a loop).

You're only doing it once, so you only get one row.

Read the manual page for this function for more information and examples. But, for now:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        print_r($row);
}
```

It's evident from your use of `$row =` inside the `print_r` expression that you did in fact take an example like this, but replaced the loop with a single `print_r` call for some reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lightness Races in Orbit. Yeah, I was trying different things and I think I mixed up the codes. You code worked pretty well. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh no sorry about that. It was an extra curly brace. Thanks!

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)